# R6025 Pure virtual function call: What is and how to resolve

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pure-virtual

**Answer can be found here:**

> [An Excerpt from Effective C++, Third Edition, by Scott Meyers](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html)

*url posted by*: [hmjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033896/hmjd)

Please read that page so you understand why it is happening. Also you know why substituting

```
        virtual void     OnRelease() = 0;
```

by:

```
        virtual void     OnRelease(){};
```

will work but isn't the correct way to resolve.

---

**Original question**

R6025: pure virtual function call

```
#include <Windows.h>

// static lib
    //file.h
    class cBaseApplication
    {
    public:
        virtual          ~cBaseApplication(){ Release(); }
        virtual void     Release()
                         {

                             OnRelease();

                         };
        virtual void     OnRelease() = 0;
    }; // class cBaseApplication

    //file1.h
    class cApplication : public cBaseApplication
    {
    public:
        virtual void     OnRelease()
                         {

                             /* what the heck do something here */

                         };
    }; // class cApplication

// executable
    // file3.h
    int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
    {

        cApplication* pApplication = new cApplication();

        /*...what the heck, do stuff...*/

        pApplication->Release();
        delete pApplication;      // R6025: pure virtual function call
        pApplication = NULL;

        return 0;

    }
```

At the line

```
delete pApplication;
```

R6025 occurs and when removing, all fine but memory leaks occur.
Removing the pointer reference the R6025 will happen too on 'program exit' when cApplication application will be destruct.

Due to the beep, the R6025 scares me :s

As it seems I have to choose between the two but I just don't want to, what is happening here?

Regards,
John

EDIT: Added some code, seems Eran is right as I do call virtual functions there

EDIT: Added to example, [ virtual void OnLostDevice() = 0; ]. Changing from abstract to ascoop gave an immediate solution. Starting to read that page in the comments below as I got the feeling I ain't there yet.

EDIT: After I got the answer I understood my own problem. So I rewrote the question, so the answer fits the question.

Thanks, John

Comment: R6025: Pure virtual function call -- which pops up in a mesagebox

Comment: @thb It is a [runtime error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125749) printed by an MSVC program.

Comment: Does the error occur in the trivially small program that you have pasted above? Or does it only occur in some other program, of which that is a fragment?

Comment: Never mind, that program doesn't even compile. I have the answer to my question. Please provide a **small**, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Do you understand that the base `Release()` will be called twice?  (And is this your intent?)

Comment: The problem may be calling a virtual function from the destructor. See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html.

Comment: this is a fragment of a framework around D3D9. cBaseApplication initializes the d3d and cApplication (wich is almost empty) implements the app specific code

Comment: #James: yes I am aware. Put it in here but tried it also when it was remove from cApplication. Same result.

Comment: @Rob: Sometimes saying nothing is saying enough. How rude.

Comment: @JohnSmith I apologize for the offense. I certainly didn't intend any.

Comment: @Rob: As it is a comment and not an answer I can't accept. But that's the only reason ;), so it's all fine. One can say something too quickly, I know and you know ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must not call virtual functions in constructors **and** in destructors. I don't see a pure virtual function here, but if `cBaseApplication::Release` happen to call one, you'll get that error every time you destruct a `cBaseApplication`. I'm not sure that's the issue because I don't have all the code, but your code calls for that kind of issues.

Comment: you are right, I do call virtual funcs in the destructor. Temporary solution, implemented an empty scope on an abstract func. Me is studying further on this answer.

Comment: Accpeted this answer is it is true.