# SQL Agent Job running SSIS error - pure virtual function call

Tags: sql, perl, visual-studio-2008, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a SSIS package which does a few things e.g. copies files between different network drives, writes files into SQL tables, truncate SQL tables, as well as calls some Perl scripts to do some scripting work on the CSV files.

The SSIS package runs perfectly locally - however when I uploaded the package to SQL Agent Job and run the job, I get the error:

```
R6025  - pure virtual function call.  The return value was unknown.  The process exit code was 255.
```

I get this pop-up error (most of the time) as well when I manually execute the SSIS package from the server (instead of through the SQL Agent job). Other times, the package executes perfectly on the server without this problem.

I'm really a bit lost - any pointers and advice would be really appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT: This is how I run the perl scripts from my SSIS:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming this an error generated from your perl package provider. [ref 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269035/r6025-pure-virtual-function-call-what-is-and-how-to-resolve) [ref 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125749) [ref 3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2df3e2ba-0b4a-4322-adfc-c9f3223380d4/r6025-pure-virtual-function-call) Something, somewhere has bad logic in it. My money's on the perl library. See if your server is matched with most recent from ActiveState/strawberry/dwim/etc

Comment: Thanks so much bilinkc!! Hmmm, but confusing why the perls runs locally and not on the server? I have downloaded the most recent strawberry from the website only this week and installed on both locally and on the server...

Comment: I assume the OS of the server is different from your local machine? You could also try setting up the same account to run SQL Agent on your machine and see if you can't induce the error. Generally, when things run well in BIDS/SSDT but not as agent, it's a permissions thing. Doesn't sound like that's the case here though

Comment: Yea doesn't seem like a permission error here...maybe something to do with me installing perl on the server. I have updated my question with a screenshot of how I am calling the perl scripts from SSIS. 
Hmm what would you recommend that I do to begin about it?

Comment: Oh and when I disable the perl job container on my SSIS, i still get the same error - does that rule out that Perl is not the culprit here?

Comment: So much for the easy approach. Yes, I would say if you disabled the perl executable and still get the error, the source must be something else. Mind popping a screenshot of your package's control flow? Does the processing of the package stop when this exception is thrown or does it seem to go about it's business? How about the installation of SQL Server itself? What is your specific build number? Any chance the server is less patched than your machine?

Comment: Yes the package stops when this exception is thrown. The R6025 error is really random and it's hard to determine what is causing it. I have disabled part of my package to test and it is never consistent when the error would strike. When I run the package on the server, sometimes SSIS tells me the execution is completed n stops, but looking at the task flow, you can tell the tasks are not completed based on the colour etc.